# How to use "resulting" and "resultant" as qualifier properly?

Tags: meaning

If I say that "the resulting object A" and "the resultant object A", do the two statements mean the same thing always, sometimes, never?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes the two statements mean the same thing.

**Resultant** is an adjective formed from the verb 'to result' which means 'that which results' e.g. 'We restructured the business with *resultant* cost savings'

**Resulting** is the present participle of that same verb which can be used in a variety of ways, one of which is as an adjective which means exactly the same thing as *resultant*. Indeed you could simply replace *resultant* in the above example with *resulting*.

However other uses of *resulting* would include:

'He had lived a dissolute life, *resulting* in serious ill health at an early age'.

'*Resulting* from the new evidence available to the defence, the prosecution decided to drop the case'.